# System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault<TSource>(...) returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

When the DB Table is empty my request to access the result throws an error.

```cs
var resultEthnie = (from k in db.N_QONV
                    where k.qonv_fk_numvol == clientId && 
                          k.qonv_fk_eon_id == 64
                    select new { k.qonv_fk_num_question }
                   ).Take(1);

return Convert.ToInt32(resultEthnie.FirstOrDefault().qonv_fk_num_question);
```

Is there a way to have a default return result value when the query result is empty?

Comment: `resultEthnie.FirstOrDefault()?.qonv_fk_num_question ?? 0`? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the type of `qonv_fk_num_question`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to have a default return result value when the query result is empty?

You are getting the error because you try to access the first element of the query result without check if it is empty or not.

To fix the issue use `?` operator after the `FirstOrDefault()` method:

```cs
resultEthnie.FirstOrDefault()?.qonv_fk_num_question; // ? will escape accessing to 
                                    // qonv_fk_num_question if the result is null
```

---

However here I see a bit more elegant solution. Instead of using filtering, select and later trying to access the first element of the result, simple use `FirstOrDefault()` method [lambda version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Queryable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Boolean___):

```cs
var result = db.N_QONV.FirstOrDefault(k => (k.qonv_fk_numvol == clientId) &&
                                           (k.qonv_fk_eon_id == 64));

return Convert.ToInt32(result?.qonv_fk_num_question);
```

Comment: The second query isn't correct. `FirstOrDefault` doesn't return `IEnumerable`. I think you forgot to remove the `Select` part. But, actually, the original query is recommended. Now you pull an entire object from the database while you only need one value.

Comment: @GertArnold, you are correct it was a copy/paste issue. What about selecting the entire object, it also has reasons to exist. In most real situations, you may need to use other properties too. This way, you will not do much back and fort changing the code. Anyway, both versions are fine, and whether or not pick one or the other is more based on personal needs.